# Pagination URL Building with wildcards

Tags: node.js

I have a URL like this

```
website.com/news/*1/*2/
```

And have two objects with arrays such as:

```
{
*1: ['april', 'may', 'june'],
*2: [28, 29, 30],
}
```

So how should I build the list of possible URLs with given wildcard data?
The final result in this case should be:

```
website.com/news/april/28/

website.com/news/april/29/

website.com/news/april/30/

website.com/news/may/28/

website.com/news/may/29/

website.com/news/may/30/

website.com/news/june/28/

website.com/news/june/29/

website.com/news/june/30/
```

I know that the count of urls = *1.length * *2.length but cannot make the correct algorithm.

P.S. the number of wildcarded URL segments is not static, can be changed [1; n]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I want. Could find after 2 days of researches.
https://github.com/luizomf/cartesianproduct